# AngularJS/CSS Move one div out and another in on the same modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on an app and want to use AngularJs for doing this :-

```
<div class="main">
<div class="one">Content 1 here ...</div>
<div class="two">Content 2 here ...</div>
</div>
```

div one contains a button which on click brings out div two and replaces div one.

Can anyone help regarding this, (Do i need to use ng-Animate or a better CSS trick) ?

EDIT: I will make it a little more clear 
Div one has a list and a button called ADD which on click brings a list which is in div two, I select what to add and then submit, the list in div one appears updated.

Comment: I assume you want there to be some kind of visible animation of the divs coming in and out?

Comment: The div two is hidden that is css is `display:none` or you want to create a template and insert it?

Comment: I have edited the question for some clarity

Answer (score 0):

[Try this JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/4tsyeLsg/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="listCtrl">
    <div class="one">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="list in lists">{{list}}</li>
        </ul>
        <button ng-click="showOptions = !showOptions">{{showOptions?'Hide':'Show'}} Options</button>
    </div>
     <div class="two" ng-show="showOptions">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="list in options" ng-click="add($index)">{{list}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('listCtrl',function($scope){

    $scope.lists =['Monday','Tuesday'];

    $scope.options =['Sunday','Saturday'];

    $scope.add = function(index){

        $scope.lists.push($scope.options[index]);
         $scope.options.splice(index,1);


    };

});
```

Comment: Click on sunday or saturday so it will be added into the list.